# OPA giving error "rego_parse_error: var cannot be used for rule name"

Tags: opa, rego

I have a simple rego file like this:

```
package example

default isApplicable := false

isApplicable if {
   timeNow := time.now_ns()
   timeNow >= input.startDatetime
}
```

and I keep getting parse error:

"rego_parse_error: var cannot be used for rule name"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that I had to have `import future.keywords.if` in my rego. After adding it the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Missing import:

```
import rego.v1
```

Or as already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76157454/8462081):

```
import future.keywords.if
```